# Convert date column formated as xx:xx.x

Tags: python, pandas

I have come across a CSV file that contains a date column formatted in the following manner: `xx:xx.x`, here's a couple of the data present in the column marked as date:

```
07:33.0
34:53.0
06:30.0
30:09.0
02:18.0
```

My question is what type of formatting is this? And how can I convert it to a proper date format using Python?

Comment: That isn't a date, it's `minutes:seconds`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like times without hours.

You can create timedeltas by add `0` hours by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
df['col'] = pd.to_timedelta('00:' + df['col'])
print (df)
              col
0 0 days 00:07:33
1 0 days 00:34:53
2 0 days 00:06:30
3 0 days 00:30:09
4 0 days 00:02:18
```

Or convert to datetimes by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) - there is added default `date`:

```
df['col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col'], format='%M:%S.%f')
print (df)
                  col
0 1900-01-01 00:07:33
1 1900-01-01 00:34:53
2 1900-01-01 00:06:30
3 1900-01-01 00:30:09
4 1900-01-01 00:02:18
```